# How can I find all the indices of a string type item(contained in a sublist) that matches a given string?

Tags: python

I have a list that has string type items in its sublists.

```
mylist = [["Apple"],["Apple"],["Grapes", "Peach"],["Banana"],["Apple"], ["Apple", "Orange"]]
```

I want to get the indices of sublist that has `Apple` only.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
get_apple_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(list(my_list)) if x == "Apple"]
print(get_apple_indices)
```

Actual output:

```
[]
```

Expected output:

```
[0,1,4]
```

Comment: `[i for i, x in enumerate(list(my_list)) if x == ["Apple"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps compare each element against a single-item list `['Apple']` instead of comparing a `list` object against a `string`.

```
get_apple_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(list(my_list)) if x == ["Apple"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really do need to match on string instead of a list for some reason, here is a solution.

From [just-so-snippets](https://github.com/called2voyage/just-so-snippets/blob/master/match-single-sublist.py):

```
match_string = "Apple"
get_matching_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(list(mylist)) if len(x) == 1 and x[0] == match_string]
```

You can see that it checks for sublists that have a length of 1 (if it has only "Apple", then it must have a length of 1), then it checks to see if the first (only) item matches the string.